# How to solve error "Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode"

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have update my website from DNN 8 to DNN 9.

Their is already a functionality to print or download in the module.

When I am downloading file it is given me below error and after that my website stop working on each event I am getting same error.

```
Exception type: LockRecursionException 
Exception message: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
```

Comment: Which module allows you to print or download a file?

Comment: We have created custom module payment succeed where we are downloading labels and invoice. label and invoice will generating at the  time of user click on download button. this problem occurring only on IIS service, when we are calling though the IIS but when we are running the code from the local host then its working fine. this is happening after upgrade version DNN ivoq 9.1.1. even its working fine in 8.5.